# make a data frame base on a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this :

```
{1:[1,2,3,4,5], 6:6 , 7:[7,8] , 9:{} , 10:{} }
```

and want to make a data frame base my dictionary like this one:

| A header | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

in fact, ***the elements that are in each dictionary value get 1 in their rows and columns***.
please help me to solve this problem.
thank you.

Comment: can you explain why you changed you example and the logic of the update? Now should both keys and values be used? What if you had `{5: [4]}`?

Comment: I don't get why the entire 1-5 block should be filled; the dict only has an entry from 1 to each, not from all to all. Can you please describe in words what the algorithm should do? Is this an adjacency map or enumerated groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {1:[1,2,3,4,5], 6:6 , 7:[7,8]}

d2 = {k:v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k,v in d.items()}

out = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(1, columns=v, index=v) for k,v in d2.items()])
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
      )
```

output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
3  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
5  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Updated question (it remains a guess on the exact logic):

```
d = {1:[1,2,3,4,5], 6:6 , 7:[7,8] , 9:{} , 10:{} }
d2 = {k:[v] if isinstance(v, int) else v for k,v in d.items()}
out = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(1, columns=v, index=v)
                  if v else
                  pd.DataFrame(0, index=[k], columns=[k])
                  for k,v in d2.items()])
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
      )
```

output:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
2    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
3    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
4    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
5    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
6    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
7    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
8    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
9    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```